# Is there a way to inject job id as an env variable into a container in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

The yaml below injects the pod's name into the container as RUN_ID. If this cron job spins up 10 pods (parallelism = 10), each of the 10 pods will have a different run id. But I want all the 10 pods to have the same run id. DownwardApi doesn't seem to support retrieving the job id. Is there any other way to do it?

In my case it is not necessary that it needs to be the job id. Any random id that could be set in all 10 pods when a new job is spin up will do. So any ideas for that will also help.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: ${CRONJOB_NAME}
  namespace: ${NAMESPACE_NAME}
spec:
  schedule: "0 8 * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 4
      parallelism: ${PARALLEL_JOBS_COUNT}
      completions: ${PARALLEL_JOBS_COUNT}
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
            image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            env:
            - name: RUN_ID
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name ---> this gets the pod's name
    .
    .
```

Comment: Cannot you simply take a pod name and extract everything but last `-\w+` segment?

Comment: Is it possible to do such extractions when setting an env variable in the yaml file? Could you please show an example of it?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Kubernetes version: 1.19.0, Provider: Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did `RUN_ID=${POD_NAME%\-*}` in a command to extract the job name from the pod name. This solved my use case.

```
 spec:
      containers:
      - name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
        image: ${ACR_DNS}/${JMETER_DOCKER_IMAGE}
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - 'export RUN_ID=${POD_NAME%\-*}; cd /config; /entrypoint.sh -n -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true -Ljmeter.engine=debug -Jjmeterengine.force.system.exit=true -t \$(JMETER_JMX_FILE)'
        env:
        - name: RUN_ID
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem today also. Similar to you, I needed to supply a **RUN_ID** environment variable that was the same for all pods in a "run" of a CRON Job, but also was unique to that run. (This was for Cypress rather than JMeter but same problem).

You can actually solve it by using:

```
- name: RUN_ID
  valueFrom:
     fieldRef:
     fieldPath: metadata.labels['job-name']
```

The job name label on each pod is consistent across pods, and the next time the job runs it generates a new unqiue job name.